# How to hide left button of the navigation bar?

Tags: ios4, uinavigationbar

How do I hide left button of the navigation bar I've created in the Interface Builder? In the Interface Builder, there is a check box *Hidden* for it, but I am not able to set it programmatically (`UINavigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem` has no such property).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make one IBOutlate for your uibarbuttonitem and them through that property hide that button
just like

`@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *hide;`

now attache it to the left barbutton item of your navigation bar in xib

now use this code

`hide.hidden = YES;`

where ever you like to hide it and to show it

`hide.hidden = NO;`

just simple

happy codding